# How to sort a list of nested dictionaries based on a deeply nested key?

Tags: python, python-3.9

I have a list that looks like this:

```py
ls = [
    {
        "max_supply": None,
        "platform": None,
        "quote": {
            "USD": {
                "fully_diluted_market_cap": 464800388135.72,
                "last_updated": "2021-10-20T13:37:02.000Z",
                "market_cap": 464800388135.7246,
                "price": 3938.871641392752,
                "volume_24h": 15411634916.820467,
                "volume_change_24h": -3.4909
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "max_supply": None,
        "platform": None,
        "quote": {
            "USD": {
                "fully_diluted_market_cap": 58764548678.52,
                "last_updated": "2021-10-20T13:37:03.000Z",
                "market_cap": 58764548678.52,
                "price": 4784.77,
                "volume_24h": 189992412916.647,
                "volume_change_24h": 85.422
            }
        }
    },
]
```

How do I order the given list by each `market_cap` value that is located in the `quote` and `USD` keys?

I have found some solutions but they are only referring to sort by the first-level dictionary keys and values, however I have not been able to find any solutions for sorting by the keys and values in a dictionary two-level deep. in the given list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a lambda function as the `key` argument for the built-in `sorted` function:

```
ls = [
    {
        "max_supply": None,
        "platform": None,
        "quote": {
            "USD": {
                "fully_diluted_market_cap": 464800388135.72,
                "last_updated": "2021-10-20T13:37:02.000Z",
                "market_cap": 464800388135.7246,
                "price": 3938.871641392752,
                "volume_24h": 15411634916.820467,
                "volume_change_24h": -3.4909
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "max_supply": None,
        "platform": None,
        "quote": {
            "USD": {
                "fully_diluted_market_cap": 58764548678.52,
                "last_updated": "2021-10-20T13:37:03.000Z",
                "market_cap": 58764548678.52,
                "price": 4784.77,
                "volume_24h": 189992412916.647,
                "volume_change_24h": 85.422
            }
        }
    },
]
sorted_ls = sorted(ls, key=lambda obj: obj["quote"]["USD"]["market_cap"])
```

Alternatively, you can use the `.sort()` method if you want to edit the list in-place.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I just added the `reverse=True` option to the `sorted()` method and it worked out like a charm, sorting from the highest to the lowest.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own function that returns a key to sort against and then use `sort` like so

```
all_data = [
    {
        "max_supply": null,
        "platform": null,
        "quote": {
            "USD": {
                "fully_diluted_market_cap": 464800388135.72,
                "last_updated": "2021-10-20T13:37:02.000Z",
                "market_cap": 464800388135.7246,
                "price": 3938.871641392752,
                "volume_24h": 15411634916.820467,
                "volume_change_24h": -3.4909
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "max_supply": null,
        "platform": null,
        "quote": {
            "USD": {
                "fully_diluted_market_cap": 58764548678.52,
                "last_updated": "2021-10-20T13:37:03.000Z",
                "market_cap": 58764548678.52,
                "price": 4784.77,
                "volume_24h": 189992412916.647,
                "volume_change_24h": 85.422
            }
        }
    },
]

def get_sort_key(current_dict):
    return current_dict['quote']['USD']['market_cap']
all_data.sort(key=get_sort_key)
print(f'Sorted dict: {all_data}')
```